# Xamaring IOS: Which UI element to use for displaying a grid of images?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm currently developing in Xamarin IOS. My goal is to display my images in a grid like view like I've done in Android (see below). My question is what UI element from Xamarin would be the most ideal to achieve this?

[image: Android example]

Comment: Try a UICollectionView:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/uicollectionview

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard `Grid` and populate it via a for loop for instance. This is less cumbersome than setting up each element in `xaml`.

> My goal is to display my images in a grid like view like I've done in
>   Android (see below).

If you use `Xamarin.Forms`, another option you have is to use this implementation of [FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView). There are samples and documentation is well explained.

I've used it in a previous project and it's pretty efficient! I think that you could easily achieve the result you need using any of these options.

HIH!